# About Berkeley DB - creating the environment home

Tags: berkeley-db

I have started playing around with Berkeley DB. This one is really interesting, but I am facing one problem.
While creating the Environment we create it like this -

```
Environment env = new Environment(new File("./bdb"), envConfig);
```

It initially threw an exception saying "bdb" location was not found. I created the location and it all worked.

My question is how would I set up berkeley DB to create this directory for me if it does not exist. I actually checked at the config method SetAllowCreate(boolean flag) .. but its functionality is different.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ended up doing something like this (not sure whether it is right solution but it works)

```
boolean x = new file("./bdb.data").mkdir();
Environment env = new Environment(new File("./bdb"), envConfig);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do -

```
File file = new File("file path goes here");
// Either the file exists or mkdirs is successful
if (file.exists() || file.mkdirs()) {
    Environment env = new Environment(file, envConfig);
}
```